# Is there a way to get a parameter from the Parameters Server as unsigned type?

Tags: ros, rosparam, getparam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to interpret a parameter in the .launch file as `unsigned int`, but I can't find (in ROS indigo) a function `getParam()` that accepts an `unsigned int&` as second parameter.

Are there any other solutions except from casting the variable?

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/218914/is-there-a-way-to-get-a-parameter-from-the-parameters-server-as-unsigned-type?/) by [d.fenucci](https://answers.ros.org/users/24372/d.fenucci/) on ROS Answers with karma: 114 on 2015-10-09

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No, I am afraid casting is the only feasible option.

---

Originally posted by [Felix Widmaier](https://answers.ros.org/users/28762/felix-widmaier/) with karma: 382 on 2017-10-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1